# Rails Devise delegate set and save both models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delegates, devise

I am using rails 3.2.1 and latest devise. This gem gives us many columns in the `User` model such as:
`current_sign_in_at, remember_created_at, last_sign_in_at`, etc
So I decide to keep my model clean and move all fields except `id,email,password,timestamps` in the table called `user_sessions`(model `UserSession`), looking for the how to resolve this i found the delegates method, but don't understand how to realize this functional. If u got any other ideas, please explain them fully.
For the first time I tried a simple example in the test application. I create 2 models: `User`(email:string) and `Profile`(user_id:integer, name:string). Here they are:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :profile
   delegate :name, :name=, :to => :profile, :allow_nil => true
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I've opened rails c and try out:

```
u = User.new #=> new user object
u.name #=> nil
u.name = 'something' #=> "something" 
u.name #=> nil
```

so I can't even set a value, because after that it still nil for some reason. I expect to change the value and save this object. Also I understand that it would save only `User`, not `Profile`, so I think about implement `before_save` where I will handle the needed value and save `Profile` object, like:

```
before_save :save_profile

def save_profile
   #get self.name and somehow save profile object
end
```

and same for update function. Could it be realized? Or suggest a better way, please. And note again that I want to implement this to the `Devise` User model. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
u = User.new #=> new user object
u.build_profile
u.name #=> nil
u.name = 'something' #=> "something" 
u.name #=> ?
```

Comment: Create works perfectly, but I got one more question: how can I update existing build? if i change `u.email='new_val'` and `u.save` it updates the `User` model, but when I try `u.name='new_val'` - `u.save` does nothing, just `(0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
 => true `

Comment: Adding a callback on the user model to save the profile would be fine